# Implementing BBC gelui with joomla 3.0

Tags: javascript, joomla3.0, icarousel

I'm using Joomla! 3.0 which is powered by Joomlashape Helix template & I'm following this tutorial

http://www.bbc.co.uk/frameworks/gelui/guides/carousel

It clearly says that I need http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html

Is this compatible with Joomla 3.0 & if so how do I activate it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page) is very useful once you have to add css / js to your template.

In your case you have to download and put the js library (require.js) in your template folder and load it using:

```
<?php
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $document->addScript(JUri::base() . 'templates/your_template/js/require.js');
?>
```

* "your_template" is your active template name.

Good luck!